# How to Create Groups of Stem Plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, rank

I want to create a stem plot in ggplot2 which shows the ranks of different models on various performance measures. So far I have managed to create the 'buds' of the stem plot using geom_point, but I can't get geom_segment to line up with the points.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
data = data.frame(Model = c("RTD", "STD", "RTC"), Measure = c("S", "n"),     rank = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2))

dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.75) 

ggplot(data = data, aes(x=Model, y=rank, color = Measure, group =   interaction(Model, Measure))) + geom_point(size=4, position = dodge) + geom_segment( aes(x=Model+dodge, xend=Model+dodge, y=0, yend=rank))
```

This doesn't work because 'dodge' isn't a numeric object, so I am unable to add it to the Model's position. Does anyone know a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `geom_segment` call to:

```
geom_linerange( aes(x=Model, ymin=0, ymax=rank), position = dodge)
```